# How to set selector on selected ViewGroup

Tags: android, selector

On my `RelativeLayout` I have created `selector` to select it permanently once clicked on it, but it's not working for me. As I add a state `state_activated` it does nothing and when I replace it with `state_pressed` it shows once and then hides as I leave the layout.

**selector**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_activated="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners
                android:bottomRightRadius="@dimen/radius_round_btn"
                android:topRightRadius="@dimen/radius_round_btn" />
            <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```